# Opengl Vertices Camera orientation

Tags: opengl, rotation, vertices

I am working on a 3D project using vertices, i started it with a simple gluLookAt in order to have a first person camera moving in an environment, i use it this way :

```
   gluLookAt(_position.x,_position.y,_position.z,
      _target.x,_target.y,_target.z,
      0,0,1);
```

Everything was working fine, i was calculating my target according to the position of the mouse and angles (theta and phi), my project moved on to using vertices for performance issues, so i had to use the same camera for these new objects, in order to do this i used the GLM library this way :

```
glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(90.0f, 800.0f / 600.0f, 0.1f, 100.f);
glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
glm::vec3(position.x,position.y,position.z),
glm::vec3(target.x,target.y,target.z), 
glm::vec3(0,0,1)  
    );

glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f); !
// Our ModelViewProjection : multiplication of our 3 matrices
glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model; 

GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(this->shaderProgram, "MVP");
```

here is the shader i use :

```
const GLchar* default_vertexSource =
"#version 150 core\n"
"in vec2 position;"
"in vec3 color;"
"out vec3 Color;"
"uniform vec3 translation;"
"uniform mat4 rotation;"
"uniform mat4 MVP;"
"void main() {"
"   Color = color;"
"   gl_Position = MVP*rotation*vec4(position.x + translation.x, position.y + translation.y, 0.0 + translation.z, 1.0);"
"}";
```

What happens is that my my object's coordinate reference is not the same as my camera, it is drawn above it on the current x/z plan whereas it should be facing the camera on the x/y plan.

Comment: After modifying my code, it appears that the camera is fine, it is just that my object is drawn at the top of it, i don't know why though if someone could lighten it up for me, that would be great.

Comment: It seems like the coordinate reference of my vertices is not the same as glLookAt, my Cube is drawn at the same than my camera but not my vertices array...

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view it seems that you are missunderstanding how translation in OpenGL works.

glm::lookAt returns one modelview matrix. -> How the objects in the scene are translated according to the camera.  In openGL you do not "Move" the camera, you are moving all the objects around the camera. 
So if you have 2 objects in 0 0 0 (origin of you world camera system) and ur camera is at 
eye(0,0,-3), center(0,0,0), up(0,1,0) and you want to move one object to the left and on object to the right you need to have a matrix stack from glm

```
std::stack<glm::mat4> glm_ProjectionMatrix;
```

Here you can push the modelview from your camera as top object.

For the object movemtn to the left side you can just use glm::translate, upload this mat4 as modelview matrix to your shader. (here do not render the scene)

Reset the top matrix to modelview (eiter pop() if you made a copy of the top element before) or just reset using glm::lookAt. Then glm::translate in the other direction.

In your vertex shader you now need no vec3 translate or rotate.

You just say

```
 gl_Position = perspective * modelview *vec4(position,1);
```

This wil update the two object accordingly to you given translation.

If you want to move some objects around, just update the modelview matrix for the one object.

http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html

I hope you can understand my answer.

The basics of movement (rot and trans) in OpenGL is matrix multipication. You do not need to add some translation vec to your modelview in the shader. GLM can do all the stuff in you c++ code

Math:

Modelview is a 4*4 matrix
If your object should not be rotated or translated the modelview is equals to the identity.

If you want to rotate the object you miltiply the modelview matrix with the correct 4*4 rotation matrix (see homogenous coordinates)

If you want to translate the vertex you multiply the correct translation to the matrix

Lets say **X = (x,y,z,w)** is you vertex

T is translation and R is rotation

a valid operation may looks like this:

**Modelview * rotation * translation *v  = v'**

**v'** is the new position of the point in your 3D coordinate system

Some examplecode you can find here: http://incentivelabs.de/Sourcecode/ See "Teil 13" or later. If you are able to understand german, you can find my tutorials on OpenGL with C++ on Youtube using the channel-name "incentivelabs"

Edit:

If I want to move an object/rotate an object using C++ with GLM

```
glm_ProjectionMatrix.top() = camera.getProjectionMat();
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocations["projection"], 1, false,glm::value_ptr(glm_ProjectionMatrix.top()));
glm_ModelViewMatrix.top() = camera.getModelViewMat();

glm_ModelViewMatrix.top() = glm::translate(
glm_ModelViewMatrix.top(),
glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -Translate));

glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocations["modelview"], 1, false,glm::value_ptr(glm_ModelViewMatrix.top()));
```

In the GLSL vertex Shader:

```
gl_Position = projection  * modelview * vec4(vertexPos,1);
```

vertexPos is an attribute (vec3 for the position)

This codes moves all vertices drawn after the upload of the modelview and projection to the shader with the same translation.

Comment: I understand modelview is all about the camera, in my code i don't mix translation of the object and "translation of the camera", in my shader the words translation and rotation correspond to the object, and the MVP is for the camera(position = camera's position), the perspective and modelview are already computed by CPU in MVP, i just wanted to apply translation and rotation of all the vertices in the shaders for better performance, I guess i could put the rotation and translation in the MVP but that wouldn't change anything would it ? am i still doing something wrong ?

Comment: So you want to have the same translation/rotation for all vertices in the scene?

Comment: I have tried to change my code according to what you said, i simply tried it just with MVP, without any rotation/translation for the object, the problem is still here so it doesn't seem that my issue comes from this point.

Comment: it doesn't really matter if i have the same translation/rotation for all vertices, the thing is not really working but you are right i probably will change it later on if i have several vertices to display.

Comment: I have tried your code but id didn't change my problem, the object is still drawn on top of the camera.

Comment: I solved my problem, it didn't come from Vertices / Opengl matrices, it came from the fact that i didn't initialize my camera target properly, it considered some part of space as the initial so that the axes reference from OpenGL world were above it... Thanks for your explanations anyway I still have some code to optimize.